# org.json.JSONObject converting number to exponential form

Tags: json, org.json

I am using org.json.JsonObject (20190722 version) to convert a string into a json object. It's converting the decimal numbers into exponential format.

```
String jsonString = "{\"value1\":12345678,\"value2\":\"Name\",\"value3\":123456789.345}";
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);
```

I am expecting output:

```
"value2":"Name","value1":12345678,"value3":123456789.345
```

But I am getting:

```
"value2":"Name","value1":123456789,"value3":1.23456789345E8
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code, with BigDecimal value you can get expected result

```
json.getBigDecimal("value3");
```